# Compare 2 dataframes and identify unique rows (Python Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table in GCP (df_1) which contains a dataset with 18 columns and 80,000 rows. I also have an .xlsx file df_2 which contains the same columns and about 40,000 rows, most of which should already be present in df_1.

I am trying to use Python Pandas to compare df_1 and df_2 and return rows which appear in df_2 but not in df_1 and then append the results to the df_1 table in GCP.

After reading both df_1 and df_2 I am trying to run the following to get the rows which do not appear in df_1 -

```
df_unique = df_2[~(df_2['Column1'].isin(df_1['Column1']) & df_2['Column2'].isin(df_1['Column2']))]
```

However this is returning all rows in df_2.

**EDIT FOR MORE CONTEXT**

| df_1_Col1 | df_1_Col2 | df_1_Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/1990 | 12345 | Monday |
| 02/01/1990 | 12345 | Tuesday |

| df_2_Col1 | df_2_Col2 | df_2_Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/1990 | 12345 | Monday |
| 02/01/1990 | 12345 | Tuesday |
| 03/01/1992 | 12222 | Saturday |

So in this scenario, I would like to return ONLY row 3 as it does not already appear in df1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the bitwise `&` operator use `and`:

```
df_unique = df_2[~(df_2['Column1'].isin(df_1['Column1']) and df_2['Column2'].isin(df_1['Column2']))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you just want that :

```
df_unique = df_2.loc[~df_2['Column1'].isin(df_1['Column1'],:]
df_1=df_1.append(df_unique)
```

Comment: Just to check, can I do this for all 18 columns -
df_unique = df_2.loc[~df_2['col1'].isin(df_1['col1'])]
df_unique = df_2.loc[~df_2['col2'].isin(df_1['col2'])]
df_unique = df_2.loc[~df_2['col18'].isin(df_1['col18'])]

Or will each line overwrite the preceding ? If this won't work, how would I combine all in 1 line.

Comment: can you tell me what you want precisely please

Comment: I want to check both data frames for rows which match exactly in all 18 columns and then return any which do not match

Comment: for each value let's say in df_1['col1'] are they unique or you can have multiple times ?

Comment: Some columns will be unique and some multiple. For example lets say df1 col1 is 'Date' there could be multiple entries on the same date. However say df1 col2 is an account number, that would be unique. 

For more context df2 is just a running tracker and df1 is a master document which is uploaded to GCP. I am trying to update any new entries on df2 to df1. So lets say my df1 was uploaded to GCP 3 weeks ago, I am trying to update any new entries on df2 within that time to df1. But it can't be based solely on date since last update etc.

Comment: ok a simple solution to check for all the columns, you create an id column. This Id column will be col1+'_'+col2+'_'+...+'col8' then you have an unique id. You do that the two dataframe and simply do then after : df_2.loc[~df_2['id'].isin(df_1['id'],:]

Comment: Great, will give it a go. I have added more context to the post if that changes anything.